# Download A File in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, blob

I am trying to download a file using ReactJS. I have the link of the file and I can actually open the file through my browser. After several attempts. Here, is my function to download the file.

```
saveFile(filename) {
    let blob = new Blob();
      if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
      } else {
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = filename;
          a.click();
          setTimeout(() => {
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
              document.body.removeChild(a);
          }, 0)
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the pop-up as expected but I get a 0 MB file downloaded.

Any ideas on how to do around this? Note that the file is `mp3`

Comment: shouldn't you pass your data and filetype while creating the blob with `new Blob`?

Comment: when I do that, the page just reloads and nothing happens

Comment: I think I got it right now. thanks so much. I wasnt pasing the data in the right format

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: tanmay , Please what attributes do I pass in blob to download a a zip ?? i have the blob like let blob = new Blob([filename], {type : 'zip/zip'} ); but it is not working propoerly

Comment: See if `application/zip` works instead of `zip/zip`

Comment: still missbehaving. downloading an error zip file